# How to erase cache of the website with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, html

My problem is that the website has some text updated, but the clients cannot see it before they erase browser cache. 
I tried

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

it causes looped reload of the page.
I tried

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='-1'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

And it has no effect on the already cashed files.
Is there any way we can clear the cache of my exact page?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can reload only if there is a cache? set for example a storage flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to empty browser cache using JavaScript code. But even if would be possible your clients would need to get fresh version of your code in first place in order it to be evaluated by their browsers which is not possible too because they use cached version at least until it becomes stale.

So for the future use of your web site you will need to configure web server to send proper caching related HTTP headers values like `Control-Control`, `Expires` and `ETag` or `Last-Modified` with response or embed them into HTML using meta tags. But your current users will need to clear browser cache manually or wait until page you change become stale in their caches. You can send them instruction how to clear browser cache. There is a [RefreshYourCache.com](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/) web site but it's a bit outdated.

For more information about cache related HTTP headers check this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed, when reading more about it, I realised that was the case.